# Why does my capacitor explode in this circuit simulator?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis

I'm new to electronics and I would like to understand why my simulator shows the capacitor exploding after I turn the switch off.

I am trying to watch the simulated voltage slowly going down from the multimeter after I turn the Slider Switch off

am I missing something obvious here? I can't see it

[image]

**Update 1:**  *after HandyHowie comment*

Removed the black cable from the switch and it worked.

[image]

Comment: A proper schematic is required, instead of this rubbish.

Comment: @LeonHeller Even though I share your dislike of fritzing, isn't the combination of a downvote *and* a close vote a bit of an overreaction? There are just 6 circuit elements, after all. While a proper schematic would be much better, the question is still understandable as it is.

Comment: @LeonHeller Since "this rubbish" -- to be precise, the behavior of a simulator -- is actually the source of the problem here, a schematic would actually obscure the issue.

Comment: When you switch it off, you are shorting the capacitor which will have been charged to 9v.  Did you intend the resistor to still be in the circuit when discharging?  You could try just removing the black wire connected to the switch.

Comment: @jms, no, the question is not understandable whatsoever. The OP hides the fact that he is using some goofy emulator, and tries to dramatize the simulation outcome showing "exploded capacitor". The question is deceptive.

Comment: @HandyHowie many thanks. After doing what you said it worked perfectly as described in my question. The voltage slowly goes down after turning the switch off. I am struggling to understand why though

Comment: Which bit don’t you understand, the fact that it is now working, or that it didn’t work before you removed the black wire?

Comment: @HandyHowie both I guess. I think I got it now. The positive side of the switch was enough to make the circuit closed when it is off.  Having said that there was no need whatsoever for the black cable. The reason the capacitor exploded is still unknown to me. Thanks for the patience, as I said, I am very beginner in electrical engineering.

Comment: I think that the simulator is exaggerating the effects of discharging the capacitor so quickly.  While it could possibly damage the capacitor, it is not going to explode in your example circuit.

Comment: If you want a fast discharge without damaging the ckt you could put a low resistance resistor in previous black wire path to ground, not making the capacitor discharge ultra quickly due to a sudden capacitor short- circuit.

Answer (score 10):

Are you observing an actual capacitor exploding, or just a simulation?

The message appearing on your picture says "capacitor is inversely polarized with -1.99nV", that is to say, a near-infinitesimal amount of electricity is going across it in the wrong direction. Substantial amounts of reverse voltage on an electrolytic capacitor can damage it, but I'm fairly certain it won't notice 2 nanovolts. The simulator is being, let's say, overly concerned. If you like, you can put a diode in series with the cap to protect it from reverse voltage in the simulator, but the real thing shouldn't need it.

Answer (score 1):

The simulator has quirks and looks middle-Eastern with polarity right to left.

Try this with a huge cap.  Note the switch Pole is in the centre and throws to either side.
[image]
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/5Qe0eDwfdal-start-simulating/editel?collectionid=OIYJ88OJ3OPN3EA&lessonid=EHD2303J3YPUS5Z&magic=bcb603ab94b437ebbd54c76cc198221ee313889a&projectid=OIYJ88OJ3OPN3EA&t=1521406113017974441&tenant=circuits#/lesson-viewer

I used C=100mF and it dies out quickly as expected with LED ESR=15 Ohms C=0.1F

I(led)=20mA  so CdV/dt=Ic  and Charge T=RC=450 Ohms * 0.1F = 45s to 64%
Discharge  ramp = ESR*C= 15*0.1F= 1.5 seconds to drop 64%
but LED dims out at -10% of Vf
so it drops in ~1.8 quickly
 then stays there as the LED current is now zero

Does this make you wonder how many Farads  are in a 9V battery?

Comment: "Charge T=RC=450 Ohms * 0.1F = 450mS" how 450 * 0.1 = 450m  ?

Comment: Brain fart.. 450*0.1= 45 s to 64% except LED Vth = 1.8V which is 20% of 9V so it charges to Vf in 14s. dV/dt=Ic/C= (V+ - Vcap)/R1*1/C = starts(9V-0)/(450*0.1)=200mV/s rise time reducing to (9-1.8V)/(450*0.1)= 160mV/s until slowly rising to 2.04V  This averages to 180mV/s to reach 1.8V or 10 seconds which is closer to result.

Comment: Since the simulator does not allow you to include ESR of Cap, battery or LED, there are some assumptions to be made. Although the LED profile seems nominal but only for Red/Yellow